# Add touch to laptop

Tags: lenovo, touchscreen

I have a new 2-in-1 Lenovo Yoga C640 laptop.

I installed Ubuntu 19.10, but the touchscreen doesn't work.

I don't know if it should, or whether I should add some package for it, and can't find this answer online.

Do you know how to add the touchscreen to my computer?

---

```
Lspci:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9b41 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f9
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 02fc
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f0
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02e8
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02e9
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02e0
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02a4
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809

xinput:
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0021:00 06CB:CDB0 Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: What is "2-1 laptop"?

Comment: My touchscreens all worked out-of-the-box. Including with the "Try Ubuntu" environment of the installer.

Comment: @Pilot6 a laptop-to-tablet :)

Comment: Do you know how to add it to my pc?

Comment: @K7AAY `xinput` or `lspci` don't need `sudo`.

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks, I've done it. I guess that since it is quite a new model, things will improve in the future.

Comment: Most likely this touchscreen is not supported yet.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for the info. It is not a problem. I understand indeed that there may be some lag time before things get tested and developed properly. It was just to be sure about it. I suppose that keeping updating the kernel, one day it will magically run without notice?

Comment: That's correct. Someone should add the support sooner or later.

Comment: I installed 3 weeks ago, Ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo Yoga C740 and the touch is working fine, the only issue is with Firefox you can't scroll with the touch ..

Comment: So, perhaps try 18.04 ?